# How to use sed to delete non alphanumerical characters for non-english languages?

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to get rid of non alphabetical characters which are following `@#$%^&*(){}[]\/` in a non-english languages.

here is an example input

```
* การันตีการเข้าถึง วันละมากกว่า 20,000 วิว (Banner A)
ทุกวันนี้ @
"เว็บไซต์ประชาไท" #
ดำเนินการผลิตข่าวและเผยแพร่บทความ อย่างต่อเนื่องผ่านเว็บไซต์ prachatai.com วันละ 10-15 ชิ้น พร้อมทั้งเผยแพร่ทาง facebook และ twitter
ทั้งหมดนี้อยู่ภายใต้การดำเนินงานของ $
$นักข่าว %
%กองบรรณาธิการ ^
&
*
(
)
[
]
\
/
```

and I have a command

```
cat test.txt | sed "s/[^[:alnum:]]//g"
```

which kind of does the job. Here is the output

```
การันตีการเขาถึงวันละมากกวา20000วิวBannerA
ทุกวันนี
เวบไซตประชาไท
ดำเนินการผลิตขาวและเผยแพรบทความอยางตอเนืองผานเวบไซตprachataicomวันละ1015ชินพรอมทังเผยแพรทางfacebookและtwitter
ทังหมดนีอยูภายใตการดำเนินงานของ
นักขาว
กองบรรณาธิการ
```

As you can see it removed the characters but it also removed the space between the words, `.` characters as well as `,` and left empty lines.

How do I remove those characters but still keep the space between words and remove unnecessary blank lines? and keep dots and commas?

is there any way to sed just a list of characters? such as `@#$%^&*(){}[]\/`?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat test.txt | sed "s/[]@#$%^&*(){}\/[]//g"
```

Note the placement of `]` at the beginning of the character class to avoid it from being treated specially.

Comment: Inside a character class, `]` needs special attention, but `[` does not.  I tend to use `s/[][…]//g` — or the negated form `s/[^][]…//g`.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out! I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html).  It is a pure filter; it only reads standard input and writes to standard output.  The `-d` option deletes the characters specified.  For your purpose, it appears that you could use:

```
tr -d '@#$%^&*(){}[]\\/' < test.txt
```

That will leave letters, digits, spaces, dots, commas, colons and semicolons alone, to name but a few.  The only gotcha is that the backslash needed to be doubled up.

Output:

```
 การันตีการเข้าถึง วันละมากกว่า 20,000 วิว Banner A
ทุกวันนี้ 
"เว็บไซต์ประชาไท" 
ดำเนินการผลิตข่าวและเผยแพร่บทความ อย่างต่อเนื่องผ่านเว็บไซต์ prachatai.com วันละ 10-15 ชิ้น พร้อมทั้งเผยแพร่ทาง facebook และ twitter
ทั้งหมดนี้อยู่ภายใต้การดำเนินงานของ 
นักข่าว 
กองบรรณาธิการ
```

The input has 15 lines; the output has 15 lines too.